# Infinite loop when reading a text file

Tags: java, buffer, inputstream, outputstream

I want to read some data from a text file. This is how the data in the text file is formatted:

```
A,20, ,0
B,30, ,0
```

And this is my code:

```
public ArrayList rechercherSalle() 
{
    String nom;
    String ligne;
    ArrayList<Salle> listeSalles = new ArrayList<Salle>();
    Salle salle = new Salle();
    try {
        InputStream flux = new FileInputStream("salle.txt");
        InputStreamReader lecture = new InputStreamReader(flux);
        BufferedReader buff = new BufferedReader(lecture);
        ligne = buff.readLine();
        while (ligne != null) {
            String[] objetSalle = ligne.split(",");
            nom = objetSalle[0];
            String capacite_maxString = objetSalle[1];
            Integer capacite_max = Integer.parseInt(capacite_maxString);
            String capacite_actuelleString = objetSalle[3];
            Integer capacite_actuelle = Integer.parseInt(capacite_actuelleString);
            String proprietaire = objetSalle[2];
            salle = new Salle();
            salle.setNom(nom);
            salle.setCapacite_max(capacite_max);
            salle.setCapacite_actuelle(capacite_actuelle);
            if(proprietaire == null || proprietaire == "" || proprietaire == "null"){
                salle.setEstReserve(Boolean.FALSE);
            } else {
                salle.setEstReserve(Boolean.FALSE);
            }
            listeSalles.add(salle);
        }
        buff.close(); 
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return listeSalles;
}
```

This code causes an infinite loop in the while loop. And the loop iterates only on the first line "A". I don't know why.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You forgot to read the next line within the loop, so `ligne` can never become `null` inside the loop:

```
        ligne = buff.readLine();
        while (ligne != null) {
            String[] objetSalle = ligne.split(",");
            nom = objetSalle[0];
            String capacite_maxString = objetSalle[1];
            Integer capacite_max = Integer.parseInt(capacite_maxString);
            String capacite_actuelleString = objetSalle[3];
            Integer capacite_actuelle = Integer.parseInt(capacite_actuelleString);
            String proprietaire = objetSalle[2];
            salle = new Salle();
            salle.setNom(nom);
            salle.setCapacite_max(capacite_max);
            salle.setCapacite_actuelle(capacite_actuelle);
            if(proprietaire == null || proprietaire == "" || proprietaire.equals("null")) {
                salle.setEstReserve(Boolean.FALSE);
            } else {
                salle.setEstReserve(Boolean.FALSE);
            }
            listeSalles.add(salle);
            ligne = buff.readLine(); // add this
        }
```

Another issue with your code is comparing `String`s with `==`. Change `proprietaire == "null"` to `proprietaire.equals("null")`.

Answer (score 4):

The way you read file is wrong.
You read line once and then `ligne` object was not modify at all during loop.
So your code should be like:

```
String line;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
   // process the line.
}
```

What you have done is:

```
String line = buff.readLine();
while (line != null) {
   // process the line.
}
```

As you said you are beginner, If you find `(line = br.readLine()) != null` condition complex then you can code like:

```
String line = buff.readLine();
while (line != null) {
   // process the line.
   line = buff.readLine(); //it should last line
}
```